# How to upgrade Xcode 4 to 4.1?

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update

After upgrading to Lion, I am getting a launch error from Xcode 4 saying it requires Snow Leopard. I see 4.1 is now a free app for Lion in the App Store, but it doesn't show up in Software Update.

If I install it from the App Store will it upgrade 4.0 or live side-by-side?

Or, do I have to uninstall Xcode first if I only want 4.1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install XCode 4.1 from the app store, which will replace XCode 4.0 with 4.1.

When updating XCode to 4.1 you will get a message to quit iTunes to continue the installation. The installation is actually waiting for iTunesHelper process to be terminated. You can terminate the iTunesHelper process using activity monitor.

On my Mac the upgrade to XCode 4.1 failed. So I needed to uninstall XCode 4.0 first.

Comment: Thanks, that iTunes error came up just like you said it would. But my upgrade was successful.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it got stuck @ 99%.  For most folks, it still works since it just didn't get the completed notification (by running Developer/Applications/XCode.app).  But for me, it crashed everytime.  To fix it, I had to run Applications/Install XCode.app again (the appstore just installs the application to install it (similar to Lion).  Hope that helps someone else...

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded Xcode 4.1 from the app store and installed it with no issues.  Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

- Download Xcode from the AppStore (you will get an installer: "Install Xcode.app")
- run the installer
- your old /Developer will be renamed into /Developer-old
- into the new /Developer you'll get installed the new Xcode
- thats all